# What is DecimalFormat and how should you use it?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm quite new to this and have been trying to figure out how DecimalFormat works. I'm not sure what part I'm doing wrong so I'll include the entire lot of code. I have two questions:

1. Is DecimalFormat a method?
2. How should I be using it to get this to work correctly, nothing I've found online has properly explained it, and just copying how they formatted it didn't work?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Eggs
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // We'll initialise some constants for the price of a dozen eggs and a loose egg. We'll also initialise the input device.
      final float PRICEDOZEN = 3.25f;
      final float PRICELOOSE = .45f;
      Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("How many eggs are you ordering? \nPRICELIST: \nONE DOZEN EGGS: $3.25 LOOSE EGGS: $0.45");
      int eggsInput = inputDevice.nextInt();
      // Here we'll initialise some variables for storing the number of dozens of eggs ordered, the number of loose eggs, and whether there 
      // is at least one dozen. We use these variables to calculate the price, and we'll also use them to clean up the output text.
      int eggsDozen = eggsInput / 12;
      int eggsLoose = eggsInput % 12;
      boolean isDozen = eggsDozen >= 1;

      // Now we'll have an if else statement, if there is at least one dozen we'll mention that in the output text, if not, we'll have different text.
      if (isDozen == true) {
      System.out.println("That's " + eggsDozen + " dozen at $3.25 per dozen, and " + eggsLoose + " loose eggs at 45 cents each.");
      // I had a problem where the '+' operator was being used for concatenation instead of arithmetic. I guessed that if you enclosed the arithmetic
      // in paranthesis (x * y + a *b) it would ensure that the arithmetic would be performed before concatenation. I was right.
      // I believe this is because concaternation is still subject to the rules of Order of Operations, so the paranthesis is performed before the addition
      // of concaternation. 

      // I've looked up online and apparently you can use "DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("#.##") to format decimal numbers. I'll try it out.
      DecimalFormat dollars = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
      System.out.println("For a total of $" + (eggsDozen * PRICEDOZEN + eggsLoose * PRICELOOSE) + ".");
      }
      else {
      System.out.println("That's " + eggsLoose + " loose eggs at 45 cents each.");
      System.out.println("For a total of " + (format.dollars(eggsLoose * PRICELOOSE)) + ". Did you know we offer a discount on eggs ordered by the dozen?");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no DecimalFormat is not a method, it is a class under java.text.

Second of all, to use DecimalFormat, you would use

```
dollars.format
```

not

```
format.dollars
```

This means that your dollars variable needs to be declared outside of your if-statement so that it can be used in your "else" statement. See the revised code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      final float PRICEDOZEN = 3.25f;
      final float PRICELOOSE = .45f;
      Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("How many eggs are you ordering? \nPRICELIST: \nONE DOZEN EGGS: $3.25 LOOSE EGGS: $0.45");
      int eggsInput = inputDevice.nextInt();

      int eggsDozen = eggsInput / 12;
      int eggsLoose = eggsInput % 12;
      boolean isDozen = eggsDozen >= 1;

      DecimalFormat dollars = new DecimalFormat("$0.00"); //now this format can be used throughout the main method

      if (isDozen == true) {
      System.out.println("That's " + eggsDozen + " dozen at $3.25 per dozen, and " + eggsLoose + " loose eggs at 45 cents each.");

      System.out.println("For a total of $" + (eggsDozen * PRICEDOZEN + eggsLoose * PRICELOOSE) + ".");
      }
      else {
      System.out.println("That's " + eggsLoose + " loose eggs at 45 cents each.");
      System.out.println("For a total of " + (dollars.format(eggsLoose * PRICELOOSE)) + ". Did you know we offer a discount on eggs ordered by the dozen?");
      }
   }
```

So when I input "25" into this system it outputs:

*That's 2 dozen at $3.25 per dozen, and 1 loose eggs at 45 cents each.*

*For a total of $6.95.*

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I had suspected that it needed to be declared outside of the if else statement, but I hadn't yet seen anything that indicated that the contents of if else statements are "nested".